# Use different values of hash in different parts of script

Tags: perl

I have a hash that I collect from a file. The below script will print all of the values as expected (note I only included important parts of the script, so opening of input file not added to not be too broad):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = ();
while (<$fh>) {
  my ($region, $site, $layer) = split;
  push @{$hash{$region}}, "$region $site $layer";
}
foreach my $values(keys %hash) {
  print $values,"\n";
}
```

My question however is that I do not want to print all the values based on the key, I actually want to split the values and print them in different areas by telling the perl what I want, and not just print `$values`.

For instance if I have the following data:

```
North belair layer2
North belair layer3
East Monte layer2
East Vista layer3
```

I actually want to be able to use the values in other areas, and print something like:

```
print "$site has layers: $layer"
```

which will print:

> belair has layers: layer2 layer3
>
> Monte has layers: layer2
>
> Vista has layers: layer3

or

```
print "$region has sites, $site and $site has layers: $layer";
```

Which will then print:

> North has sites: belair and layers: layer2 layer3
>
> East has sites: Monte Vista and layers: layer2 layer3

When I run multiple `foreach` loops I get duplicated results, and I am not sure which direction to goto anymore. Each search I have done only shows me how to print all `$values` for `key`

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer, but instead of your current `push`, you could do something like `push @{$hash{$region}->{$site}}, $layer`. And then iterate with three nested `foreach` (one for the regions, one for the sites and one for the layers). Hope it helps.

Comment: @Dada thank you for that, let me try it quick.

Comment: @Dada how do I run each if the foreach then? `foreach my $values(keys %hash)` gets values from `%hash` and there is only one hash?

Comment: Could do `for my $region (keys %hash) { for my $site (keys %{$hash{$region}}) { say "$site has layers: @{$hash{$region}->{$site}}" }}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my %sites;
my %regions;
while (<>) {
   my ($region_id, $site_id, $layer_id) = split;

   # Use hashes instead of arrays to remove duplicates.    
   ++$sites{$site_id}{layers}{$layer_id};
   ++$regions{$region_id}{layers}{$layer_id};
   ++$regions{$region_id}{sites}{$site_id};
}

# "Flatten" hashes into sorted arrays of unique elements.
for my $site_id (keys(%sites)) {
   my $site = $sites{$site_id};
   $site->{layers} = [ sort keys(%{ $site->{layers} }) ];
}

for my $region_id (keys(%regions)) {
   my $region = $regions{$region_id};
   $region->{layers} = [ sort keys(%{ $region->{layers} }) ];
   $region->{sites}  = [ sort keys(%{ $region->{sites}  }) ];
}

# Now do what we want to do.
for my $site_id (sort keys(%sites)) {
   my $site = $sites{$site_id};
   print "$site_id has layers @{ $site->{layers} }\n";
}

for my $region_id (sort keys(%regions)) {
   my $region = $regions{$region_id};
   print "$region_id has sites @{ $region->{sites} } and layers @{ $region->{layers} }\n";
}
```

Comment: just a quick question, I am trying to understand what this does exactly. `++$sites{$site_id}{layers}{$layer_id}` I can see it works, but cannot get my head around this formula.

Answer (score 3):

For the direct question: iterate over keys and for each split the value into variables

```
foeach my $region (sort keys %hash) {
    my ($region, $site, $layer) = split ' ', $region;
    ...
}
```

which you can then use for your first desired print.

However, two notes are in order.

Why is `$region` a part of a value when it is the key? Instead why not

```
...
push @{$hash{$region}}, "$site $layer";
```

so that you associate sites and layers with a region.

More to the point, there are entries for region which have same sites and you clearly need all layers for a site within a region.  Then you may want a nested structure

```
%hash = ( region => { site => [ layer, ... ], ... }, ... )
```

which you can populate with

```
while (<$fh>) {
    my ($region, $site, $layer) = split;
    push @{$hash{$region}->{$site}}, $layer;
}
```

From this you can carry out your second print, of all layers within sites in a region

```
foreach my $region (sort keys %hash) {
    print "$region has sites: ", 
        join(' and ', keys %{$hash{$region}}), ", with layers: ";
    foreach my $site (keys %{$hash{$region}}) {
        print "@{$hash{$region}->{$site}} "
    }
    say ''; 
}
```

what prints

```
East has sites: Vista and Monte, with layers: layer3 layer2 
North has sites: belair, with layers: layer2 layer3
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your input, I understand this alot better now! Upvoted your answer.